# GCC warning with c type casting

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I was trying to compile an old project on a new system, but I got a "cast from pointer to integer of different size" warning with the new system.

Here's the source code:

```
void mem_fill(char *myptr, char *mystr, uint32_t sz)
{           
    uint32_t len = strlen((const char*)mystr);
    if (len > sz) len = sz;
    memset(myptr, (int)NULL, sz); // <-- Warnning reported here
    memcpy(myptr, mystr, len);
}
```

NULL is defined like:

```
#define NULL    (void *)0
```

The old system won't report this error, it's RHEL4, gcc version 3.4.4 20050721.
New system is Cent OS 6.5, gcc version 4.4.7 20120313

I tried to replace casting type "int" with "long", then the new system won't report this error again, it looks like new system has 64 bit pointer. 
However, if I replace "int" with long/char/short, all types can pass build on the old system.

Here's my question, why does new system report this casting warning but old system doesn't? The source code is the same, so is there any other default settings for gcc hidden somewhere in the developing environment?

**It's a good point of view that this function is equivalent to strncpy. Actually my problem is - why doesn't my old system report this casting warning but new system does, is it caused by different version of GCC?**

**Thanks all guys for your help.**

Comment: I want to amplify what @MattMcNabb has said, in the case where `strlen(myptr) >= sz` the resulting string will not be null-terminated.  This is almost certainly a bug.  If (as is probable) a null terminated string is required, change `if(len > sz) len = sz;` to `if(len >= sz) len = sz-1;`.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala "This is almost certainly a bug." -- Not so certain. This function as written is equivalent to `strncpy`, with all its faults.

Comment: Also, the first line is "`const`-confused". It should be `size_t len = strlen(mystr);`. You never need to cast *to* `const` like that.

Comment: @JimBalter, that's a good point about the similarity to `strncpy`, that does make me less certain its a bug.  Yet I still have little confidence in the original writer of the function, given the weird little things like `(int)NULL` and the unneeded const-cast.  ktan would be wise to check for null-termination bugs.

Comment: "ktan would be wise to check for null-termination bugs" -- as is the case for every application of strncpy. I think the standards committees and vendors should put it on the obsolescence path.

Comment: The cast to `int` indicates there was a problem before that someone avoided by the cast; now the compiler doesn't let you get away with that. The code was always wrong; NULL is a null pointer constant, but the argument is supposed to be a byte (e.g. `'\0'`, which would be my preferred replacement for NULL. The cast on the argument to `strlen()` is also pointless; one is left wondering what was who thinking (were they thinking?) when that was added.  Usually, there is a reason — a historical reason — for such pointless casting. But those reasons should be reevaluated. Avoid casts when you can.

Comment: "why doesn't my old system report this casting warning but new system does" -- that has already been answered by Yu Hao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `0` directly instead of `(int)NULL`.

```
memset(myptr, 0, sz);
```

There's no warning in the old system is probably because `NULL` is defined as:

```
#define NULL 0
```

Both definitions of `NULL` is legal in standard C.

Answer (score 4):

Change `(int)NULL` to `0`. The argument is supposed to be a byte value to fill the memory in with, whoever wrote that code the first time didn't understand the difference between a null pointer and a byte of value zero.

Comment: Bear in mind that this code generates a null-terminated string if and only if the string was shorter than the buffer,  if I were porting this code I'd definitely go through all of the invocations of this function and check that it didn't try to assume null termination.

Comment: This function is equivalent to `strncpy`, the use of which is often (in fact usually) a bug.

Comment: Yeah. I prefer this version though, as when you see `strncpy` in someone else's code you always have to wonder if they intended something else.

Comment: Yes, but we have to wonder whether they intended something else here too -- that was the point of your warning, after all.